# d3.js development workflow

Tags: javascript, d3.js, workflow

I am running a website using a lot of d3js data viz and I'd like to package them as a separate module or lib.

So far, I have implemented a similar scaffholding and build process as d3's main repo (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/):

```
"prepublish": "npm test && rm -f package.js src/start.js d3.js d3.min.js d3.zip && bin/start > src/start.js && bin/meteor > package.js && smash src/d3.js | uglifyjs - -b indent-level=2 -o d3.js && bin/uglify d3.js > d3.min.js && chmod a-w d3.js d3.min.js package.js && zip d3.zip LICENSE d3.js d3.min.js",
```

This works fine to build the lib and is very convenient.

Now I'd like to know what the best workflow for developing the lib. I'd like to add watch functions + a livereload to test my charts easily.

What would be the best way to integrate this to the current workflow?

Many thanks